# Infix to postfix calculator produces prefix and sometimes keeps on running

Tags: java, postfix-notation, infix-notation

I'm trying to code an infix to postfix calculator. So far what I have got after inserting infix expression is either a prefix expression or the code keeps on running and does nothing. Here is what I've made:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;

public class postFix {

    public static StringBuilder postFixExp = new StringBuilder();

    public static int priority(char ch){
        if(ch == '^') return 3;
        if(ch == '/' || ch == '*') return 2;
        if(ch == '+' || ch == '-') return 1;
        return 0;
        }


    public static String postfix(){ 
        Stack<Character> st = new Stack<Character>();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Sisestage infiks: ");
        String sone = scan.next();
        scan.close();

        for(int i = 0; i<sone.length(); i++){
            char ch = sone.charAt(i);

            switch(ch){
            case'+': 
            case'-': 
            case'*': 
            case'/': 
                postFixExp.append(' ');
                st.push(ch);
                break;

        //  case' ':
            case'(':    
                st.push(ch);
                break;

            case')': 
                while(st.peek() != '('){
                    postFixExp = postFixExp.append(st.pop());                   
                }
                st.pop();
                break;
            default:
                while(!st.isEmpty() && st.peek() != '(' && priority(ch) <= priority(st.peek()))
                {
                    postFixExp = postFixExp.append(st.pop());
                }
                st.push(ch);
                break;          
            }
        }
        while(!st.isEmpty()){
            postFixExp = postFixExp.append(st.pop());
        }
        return postFixExp.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(postfix());
    }
}
```

I used [this pseudocode](http://andromeda.rutgers.edu/~loftin/datafal06/).

What's wrong with my code?

If I input :

```
1+2
```

It returns

```
+12
```

I would like to see

```
1 2 + or 12+
```

Comment: Can you give a simple example of some specific input you're providing to your program, what output you expect from it, and what output you're actually getting?

Comment: It looks like you're popping the operator off the stack and adding it to your expression, inside the `while` loop in the `default` branch.  This is before you're pushing the number onto the stack.  That's why the operator is showing up first.  You could try moving `st.push(ch)` up to above the `while` loop.

Comment: It seemed to do the trick. Thank you.